# How do I find the number of attachments in a message containing a command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a bot so that when people type `**archive` and attach an image, it will send that image to our "meme archive" channel and mention them so we know who put it there. I am trying to find a way to make it so it will only run if an attachment is sent with the message and I want the bot to say something along the lines of "Please attach an image to archive it!", to the channel the `**archive` command was sent in.

```js
if (message.content === prefix + 'archive'){
        const archivechannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '783158839847157810');
        var msgattachment = (message.attachments)
        archivechannel.send ('Archived by ' +  '<@' + message.author.id + '>' + ' ' + msgattachment.array()[0].url);
    }

    });
```

Comment: Basically `if (!message.attachments.size) { message.channel.send('please attach image') }`

Comment: @cherryblossom Yes, thank you! I looked at that before, I was just having issues trying to figure out where to put it within the first if statement. I got it, thanks again!